# Flutter Web - Where to store a Key of Encryption AES-256?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions, flutter-web

I have a Flutter web application and I need to encrypt data before send them in Firestore.

I want to know if I store the key in Cloud Function is a safe way?

Did you have an other solution about it?

Comment: Why do you need to encrypt it? That should tell you who you want to protect the key from / against what attack you want to defend yourself.

Comment: I don't want to see the clear text-plain in the Firestore from the console.

Comment: No need to encrypt anything then. Just either do not look at it, base64 encode it, just shift every character by one, etc. Since you do not encrypt it for security purposes it really does not matter what you do or where you store the key.

Comment: I do need encrypt it about security both.